# Finished the Curious badge, but haven't received it?

Tags: support, badges

The badge Curious involves getting a 5-day positive question streak. I have done that.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Photo of failed badge]

You can see I've completed the badge. Its meter is filled. What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the little popup when you click the badge progress, does it look like this?

[image: Curious Badge Popup]

The Curious badge has two components: 5 upvoted questions asked over 5 separate days, **and** maintaining a positive question record. That little 'x' turns into a tick once you have met that requirement:

[image: Socratic Badge Popup]

The formula used to calculate a positive question record is as follows:

> `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`
>
> <sub>[How is a “positive question record” calculated? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/179041)</sub>

I can't see that popup on your profile, but doing the math manually, it doesn't seem like you've met the requirement, plugging your stats in to the formula I get:

```
(12 - 2 - 3 - 2)/12 
= 5/12 
= 0.41
```

Note that negatively voted, closed **and** deleted questions do count **3 times**, so one or two poorly received questions can tip the scale. Also note that the actual *vote* score of your questions doesn't matter. If you have a question with 20 upvotes, that still only counts as 1 positive question, not 20.

So to earn Curious, you'll have to put in the hard work to raise your positive question record - either by revisiting closed questions and attempting to make them more acceptable (clarify, reduce the scope etc), or by asking new, clear, well-received questions.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the badge awarding script hasn't run yet - it's not, as far as I remember, an instant thing. I believe it only runs once per day (or a certain number of times, but not all the time).

Give it time, it should pop up within the next day at most.

Comment: If I remember it runs at midnight UTC-0. i could be wrong though